# Connecting a device to a CPU via USB PCB tracks

Tags: usb, pcb-design

I have a device that should be connected to the CPU via USB 3.0, and I am planning to put both the CPU and this device on the same PCB, so I am thinking of using PCB tracks to connect them.

My questions:

1. Is there any problem in the above way of connecting the two devices?
2. What type of consideration do I need to take of?
3. Can I do just connect the wires to each other, or do I need some type of interface?
4. Do I need all the normal surge/over voltage and ... on this design?
5. Is there any sample schematic that I can use as reference?

Comment: Question lacks significant research

Comment: Be more specific than "CPU" and "device", and yes there are considerations, you can't just 'connect' them. High speed (+50Mhz) connections require rigorous design

Comment: @laptop2d: what do you need to know about the devices and CPU? I know that the PCB design needs a lot of attention, bit from the schematic design, do I need any specific design?

Comment: What they are for starters, like a link to a datasheet. What kind of USB3.0 controller your using, and the interface of the controller. What the CPU is what kind of GPIO ports and what speeds they run at, and if it has transceivers on it. A block diagram of your system. Your question reads like this: "I want to assemble a car, do I need some kind of linkage between the engine and transmission?" It really depends on the car, the engine and what kind of transmission you have

Comment: @laptop2d: the CPU is Intel Apollo Lake and the device is based on Cypress EZ-USB FX3 chip and they should work on full speed.

Comment: Do you know how impedance match traces? Have you ever implemented a DDR interface?

Comment: @laptop2d I am not worried on PCB layout as I will use experienced people to do the PCB. I am looking at the schematic at this stage and I am looking for a sample schematic for example when a CPU is connected to a USB hub on a board .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there any problem in the above way of connecting the two devices?
> 2. What type of consideration do I need to take of?
> 3. Can I do just connect the wires to each other, or do I need some type of     interface?
> 4. Do I need all the normal surge/over voltage and ... on this design?
> 5. Is there any sample schematic that I can use as reference?

My answers:

1: No, there is no problem in connecting two USB devices (a device to a host) on the same board. It is called "embedded USB".

2 and 3:  You need to provide trace layout that conforms to USB3 signal integrity requirements, just straight connection, Rx to Tx, Tx to Rx, with AC decopling caps, all as a normal USB connector will provide.

4: No, you don't need any "normal" surge/overvoltage etc. protection, since the link is embedded, and there is nothing to protect it against.

5: It might be difficult to find. All laptop docking stations should be using embedded chips, including Super-Speed chips. In general, look for USB 3.0 design guides, similar to [**this one**](http://www.cypress.com/file/52741/download), or [**TI guide**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sllu149e/sllu149e.pdf).

ADDITION: I would advise to arrange for some power sequencing between the SoC and FX3, to force the FX3 to come up after the SoC gets ready. It can be done via power gating, or keeping the FX3 in reset using some GPIO. It would help to avoid accidents when FX3 side would go into "compliance mode" (test mode) if SoC starts with SS termination but wouldn't be ready to respond to LFPS handshake in time. It is better be safe than sorry.

Comment: thanks. I am looking at the schematic at this stage and I am looking for a sample schematic for example when a CPU is connected to a USB hub on a board, so I cab find what type of decoupling do I need and what can I remove (for example surge protectors)